# error trying to update data in 3 tables check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mariadb

I get an error when i try to run this query,
heck the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version....
please check whats wrong and how to fix that?
i have used this code to select 3 tables and its work great,
i have modify it to update the data in 3 tables.
hoping somone can help

```
$get_user_id = $_GET['id'];     
$userlogin = $_POST['user_login'];  
$nicename = $_POST['user_nicename'];

    UPDATE 
       wp_users, wp_usermeta, wp_ihc_user_levels


      FROM wp_users
           INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS usermeta_firstname
                     ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_firstname.user_id
                    AND usermeta_firstname.meta_key = 'first_name'

            INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS usermeta_lastname
                     ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_lastname.user_id
                    AND usermeta_lastname.meta_key = 'last_name'

            INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS usermeta_original_link
                     ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_original_link.user_id
                    AND usermeta_original_link.meta_key = 'original_link'

            INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS usermeta_new_link
                     ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_new_link.user_id
                    AND usermeta_new_link.meta_key = 'new_link'

            INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS usermeta_exp_link
                     ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_exp_link.user_id
                    AND usermeta_exp_link.meta_key = 'exp_link' 


    INNER JOIN wp_ihc_user_levels ON wp_ihc_user_levels.user_id = wp_users.ID


    SET wp_usermeta.user_login = '21'
        wp_usermeta.user_nicename = '$nicename',
        wp_usermeta.user_email = '$email',
        wp_usermeta.user_registered = '$registered',
        wp_usermeta.user_activation_key = '$activation',
        wp_usermeta.user_status = '$status',
        wp_usermeta.display_name = '$display_name',
        usermeta_original_link.meta_key = '$original',
        usermeta_new_link.meta_key = '$new',
        usermeta_exp_link.meta_key = '$exp_link',
        wp_ihc_user_levels = '$level'   



    WHERE wp_users.ID = '$get_user_id'
```

Comment: Neither MariaDB nor MySQL support `FROM` clauses in updates.

Comment: That query looks like it is RAW. You have to place it in quotes and then pass that string to a function call to get it passed to the database for execution

Comment: From is not a valid syntax in an update query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
UPDATE wp_users JOIN
       wp_usermeta usermeta_firstname
       ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_firstname.user_id AND
          usermeta_firstname.meta_key = 'first_name' JOIN
       wp_usermeta usermeta_lastname
        ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_lastname.user_id AND
           usermeta_lastname.meta_key = 'last_name' JOIN
       wp_usermeta AS usermeta_original_link
       ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_original_link.user_id AND
         usermeta_original_link.meta_key = 'original_link' JOIN
       wp_usermeta usermeta_new_link
       ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_new_link.user_id AND
          usermeta_new_link.meta_key = 'new_link' JOIN
       wp_usermeta usermeta_exp_link
       ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_exp_link.user_id AND
          usermeta_exp_link.meta_key = 'exp_link' JOIN
       wp_ihc_user_levels
       ON wp_ihc_user_levels.user_id = wp_users.ID
    SET wp_usermeta.user_login = '21'
        wp_usermeta.user_nicename = '$nicename',
        wp_usermeta.user_email = '$email',
        wp_usermeta.user_registered = '$registered',
        wp_usermeta.user_activation_key = '$activation',
        wp_usermeta.user_status = '$status',
        wp_usermeta.display_name = '$display_name',
        usermeta_original_link.meta_key = '$original',
        usermeta_new_link.meta_key = '$new',
        usermeta_exp_link.meta_key = '$exp_link',
        wp_ihc_user_levels = '$level'   
    WHERE wp_users.ID = '$get_user_id' ;
```

Note:  You are munging the query string with constant values.  That is a really, really bad idea.  You want to use *parameters* to pass values into the query.

Comment: if you- are talking about: exp_link is to found this correct colum (wordpress made this)
if you are talking about this: wp_usermeta.user_login = '21' ?
its just for testing
thank you so much for correcting me, its working

Comment: @ygalbrami . . . I am talking about `= '$nicename'` and so on.  These should be parameters.

Comment: can you show me how?
also i have notice that after the first join you dont put a comma between the 2 table, is need to be like this?

Comment: @ygalbrami . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have make a mistake in my code,
the correct code is:

```
UPDATE wp_users JOIN
   wp_usermeta AS usermeta_firstname
   ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_firstname.user_id AND
      usermeta_firstname.meta_key = 'first_name' JOIN
   wp_usermeta AS usermeta_lastname
    ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_lastname.user_id AND
       usermeta_lastname.meta_key = 'last_name' JOIN
   wp_usermeta AS usermeta_original_link
   ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_original_link.user_id AND
     usermeta_original_link.meta_key = 'original_link' JOIN
   wp_usermeta AS usermeta_new_link
   ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_new_link.user_id AND
      usermeta_new_link.meta_key = 'new_link' JOIN
   wp_usermeta AS usermeta_exp_link
   ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_exp_link.user_id AND
      usermeta_exp_link.meta_key = 'exp_link' JOIN
   wp_ihc_user_levels
   ON wp_ihc_user_levels.user_id = wp_users.ID
SET wp_usermeta.user_login = '21'
    wp_usermeta.user_nicename = '$nicename',
    wp_usermeta.user_email = '$email',
    wp_usermeta.user_registered = '$registered',
    wp_usermeta.user_activation_key = '$activation',
    wp_usermeta.user_status = '$status',
    wp_usermeta.display_name = '$display_name',
    usermeta_original_link.value = '$original',
    usermeta_new_link.value = '$new',
    usermeta_exp_link.value = '$exp_link',
    wp_ihc_user_levels = '$level'   
WHERE wp_users.ID = '$get_user_id'
```